# Who has precedence?

Tags: excel, refresh

If there's only one user who has "can edit" permission and he has it open on his Desktop, do his changes over write what a "can view only" user is seeing in Excel Online? When would the viewer see the changes in the browser version?

Answer (score 1):

The read only user can see the modifications when Edit user saves the Excel file.